# Erro ao tentar enviar e-mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, envio-de-email

Estou tentando enviar e-mails (usando minha conta hotmail) e estou me deparando com o erro abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não
>   respondeu\r\ncorretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão
>   estabelecida falhou\r\nporque o host conectado não respondeu
>   65.55.176.126:25

O método que estou usando está abaixo:

```
public void sendEMailThroughHotMail()
        {
            try
            {
                //Mail Message
                MailMessage mM = new MailMessage();

                //Mail Address
                mM.From = new MailAddress("xxxx@hotmail.com");

                //receiver email id
                mM.To.Add("xxxxx@gmail.com");

                //subject of the email
                mM.Subject = "your subject line will go here";

                //add the body of the email
                mM.Body = "Body of the email";

                mM.IsBodyHtml = true;

                //SMTP client
                SmtpClient sC = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");

                //port number for Hot mail
                sC.Port = 25;

                //credentials to login in to hotmail account
                sC.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@hotmail.com", "xxxxxx");

                //enabled SSL
                sC.EnableSsl = true;

                //Send an email
                sC.Send(mM);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Também tentei fazer o envio através do gmail, mas o Google interpretou minha tentativa de envio como uma tentativa de ataque ¬¬

Comment: Já tentou fazer o uso da porta 465?

Comment: @HiagoSouza tentei agora, e o erro apresentado é exatamente o mesmo: "Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu\r\ncorretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou\r\nporque o host conectado não respondeu 65.55.163.152:465"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro entre no seu webmail e habilite o POP/IMAP  no **hotmail** a configuração fica em: ***opções / Conectar dispositivos e aplicativos com POP*** depois na mesma tela tem o link ***Outras maneiras de se conectar à sua caixa de entrada*** onde terá as configurações que você precisa utilizar (endereço, porta, ssl, tls).

Para o e-mail do **gMail**, também é necessário fazer a habilitação para uso de POP/IMAP e além disso tem uma configuração de segurança que também precisa ser liberada, só que não me lembro o caminho agora.Também tem a página de ajuda com as informações de configuração de acesso.

Answer (score 2):

Ao tentar enviar o email na porta 25 você não pode ter o SSL ativo.

A porta [25 foi fechada pelos provedores no brasil](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAAahUKEwjj5s6h2_bIAhXFjZAKHUqPBag&url=http%3A%2F%2Fconvergenciadigital.uol.com.br%2Fcgi%2Fcgilua.exe%2Fsys%2Fstart.htm%3Finfoid%3D32179%26sid%3D4&usg=AFQjCNEC7WXQawOLo7rSzHckIpeI570avw&sig2=aBTo8tm2Z0eOKbxna7GjgQ), não sei se isso pode ter algum problema.

Mas para resolver seu problema faça uso do SSL sobre a porta 465.

> Exemplo

```
public void sendEMailThroughHotMail()
        {
            try
            {
                //Mail Message
                MailMessage mM = new MailMessage();

                //Mail Address
                mM.From = new MailAddress("xxxx@hotmail.com");

                //receiver email id
                mM.To.Add("xxxxx@gmail.com");

                //subject of the email
                mM.Subject = "your subject line will go here";

                //add the body of the email
                mM.Body = "Body of the email";

                mM.IsBodyHtml = true;

                //SMTP client
                SmtpClient sC = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");

                //port number for Hot mail
                sC.Port = 465;

                //credentials to login in to hotmail account
                sC.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@hotmail.com", "xxxxxx");

                //enabled SSL
                sC.EnableSsl = true;

                //Send an email
                sC.Send(mM);

            }
```

Comment: Tentei agora, e o erro apresentado é exatamente o mesmo: "Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu\r\ncorretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou\r\nporque o host conectado não respondeu 65.55.163.152:465"

Comment: @GleisonFrança , habilite o tel net e tente conectar na porta 465. `telnet 65.55.163.152 465` pode ser bloqueio no seu firewall, porque não tem mais  nada de errado. Desabilite o firewall do windows e tente novamente. Se for o caso desabilite o antivirus, pois não é um erro de programação. Você simplesmente não consegue alcançar o host de destino.

Comment: Você esta na empresa ou na sua casa? Caso esteja na empresa verifique se possui acesso por ip na porta 465, as vezes é só o firewall rssss

Comment: não tinha pensado nisso. realmente não como acessar da empresa. O lance é que tentei o mesmo código de casa ontem a noite e obtive o mesmo erro. Mas vou tentar com essa porta de casa hoje a noite. Valeu pela força!

Comment: Tente desabilitar o firewall, as vezes está havendo algum bloqueio.. o Telnet ajuda nesses casos

Answer (score 1):

Olá tente assim.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder Body = new StringBuilder();
            Body.Append("Aqui vai meu teste vamos ver se chega!!!!! :)");


            String HostSmtp = "smtp.live.com";
            String LoginSmtp = "xxxxxx@hotmail.com";
            String PasswordSmtp = "xxxxx";
            Int32 PortaSmtp = 587;

            SmtpClient Smtp = new SmtpClient(HostSmtp, PortaSmtp);
            Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            Smtp.EnableSsl = true;

            Smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(LoginSmtp, PasswordSmtp);

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            mail.From = new MailAddress("xxxxx@hotmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxxx@hotmail.com"));

            mail.Subject = "Teste de envio de email";
            mail.Body = Body.ToString();

            var Status = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                Smtp.Send(mail);
                Status = "Ok";
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Status = exc.Message;
            }
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[veja o link aqui](http://www.danresa.com.br/fabrica-de-software/index.php/configurar-envio-de-e-mails-com-porta-587-ou-porta-465/)